# What is my “special reward” for the mid summer brawl?

Tags: hearthstone

In the mid-summer brawl with mini-rag, you can get his attack up at the end of the turn by him incinerating enemies, but at a certain point it says to destroy a certain number of minions for a “special reward”.  Other than my guaranteed pack, I didn’t get anything “special”.  What is the special reward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've killed a certain number of minions during the Brawl, your wow emote will shoot Fireworks off!

- **8 Minions Killed** - Level 1 Fireworks
- **30 Minions Killed** - Level 2 Fireworks
- **60 Minions Killed** - Level 3 Fireworks

[Source](http://www.hearthpwn.com/news/2960-celebrate-midsummer-fire-festival-with-the)

Comment: Does this last forever, or is it just until the mid-summer event ends?

Comment: @Alex I haven't read anything official, but I'm pretty sure it's only durring the event